# Mail server return different certificate chain on linux and windows

Tags: java, ssl

Code in java, try to send mail.
Core dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Mail related code:

```
HtmlEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();
htmlEmail.setHostName(HOST); // e.g. mail.corp_name.com
htmlEmail.setSocketTimeout(60000);
htmlEmail.setSocketConnectionTimeout(60000);
htmlEmail.setAuthentication(userName, password);
htmlEmail.setPopBeforeSmtp(true, HOST, userName, password);
htmlEmail.setCharset("UTF-8");
htmlEmail.setSSLOnConnect(true);
htmlEmail.setFrom(this.userName, sendMaster);
htmlEmail.setSubject(sendSubject);
htmlEmail.setHtmlMsg(msg);
htmlEmail.send();
```

Same code, same jar.
When run on linux(java version is "1.8.0_131"), the process succeed in sending mail.
When run on windows(java version is "1.8.0_202"), the process fail to send mail.
And the exception is
"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

I add '-Djavax.net.debug=all', rerun, and find that:
On linux, the certificate chain I get from the server is sth. like:

```
chain [0] = [
[  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mail.corp_name.com
```

On windows, the certificate chain I get from the server is sth. like:

```
chain [0] = [
[  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=*.corp_name.com
```

Why does the server returns the certificate of 'mail.corp_name.com' on linux(which is what I desired),  but returns the certificate of '*.corp_name.com' on windows(which is not what I desired)?

Comment: Does the Windows system have an 'antivirus' or other 'endpoint security' product installed that has a feature described as 'TLS inspection' or 'web safety' or anything like that? Look at the whole cert chain (intermediate and possibly root certs) not just the leaf cert. Also are both machines connected to the same network in the same way, and did you try changing the network connection of at least one and perhaps both?

Comment: PS javamail below 1.5.3 can't do TLS better than TLSv1.0 (which Java calls just TLSv1); this protocol is now considered broken and unsafe and no public system will accept it. In a corporate/organization environment it _may_ still be allowed, but if any authority performs or requires a cybersecurity audit -- for example if you are in a financial or medical/healthcare field, or involved with any hazmat issues -- you may find it suddenly stops working.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
Thanks for your reply.
About 'endpoint security', yes, I have a endpoint security installed on windows. I never thought about these things.
And 'the whole cert chain', on linux, there are 'chain[0]' and 'chain[1]', and I can see 'chain[1]'(perhaps the root certificate?) is the certificate finally trusted. On windows, I can only find that chain[0] of '*.corp_name.com'. And the tons of other contents in chain[*] is still too hard for me to comprehend.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
And about the connection, yes, two machines connect to the mail server in different networks. Linux is in the production environment, and windows in, so to speak, test environment. And I don't have the authority to change the network.
From your reply, I can see that this problem is highly related to the network environment of the macine, not just some java or ssl config issues.
I decide to put this problem aside for the moment.